# My form box won't actually grow but instead a non usable white block appears otuside it

Tags: html, css

I am making a website that sends out newsletters for my business. My issue is that I want one big text box but the text box is not actually working.
http://pastebin.com/W6D0wvYc

Comment: What you mean under "big text box", is it `input`?

Comment: Yeah I want people to input their email address.

Comment: So, you need make it larger?

Comment: @user3674383 use a <textarea> if you want a bigger text box or set a size of an <input> as AleshaOleg hints at

Comment: How do I implement Textarea with my current code?

Answer (score 0):

First you should check your html syntax, the file isn't well formed (e.g. two closing form tags, an unclosed div tag, etc.).

A bigger text input can implemented with:

```
<textarea name="mymailtext" cols=40 rows=6></textarea>
```

You can put it over your submit input tag.